# Remove components from standard installation of KDE Plasma on Debian 10

Tags: debian, kde, plasma5

I recently Installed Debian 10 with KDE Plasma desktop environment. I chose this desktop environment because it is modern and looks great. The customization is also over the top making it the best flavor out there for me.

I noticed that it comes with a lot of bloatware which I can't seem to uninstall. The reason for this is that removing those packages will also remove other important packages.

I will put a list here with all the packages I am willing to remove, and what other packages will automatically be removed with them.

- Okular(document viewer) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- Gwenview(image viewer) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- Kaddressbook - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- Akregator(feed reader) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- Kopete(messenger) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- kmail - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- konqueror - *kde-baseapps kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard konq-plugins task-kde-desktop*
- juk(music player) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*
- Dragon player(video player) - *kde-standard, task-kde-desktop*

The list goes on like this. I do not want to write all of them down, you probably get the idea.

If possible I want to remove all programs, but of course keep using KDE. Is there a way to remove these programs safely? And if not, is there a way to hide them from my program menu? I do not need any of them and it is bothering me a lot that they are there.

Comment: install the individual kde packages you want and don't use the metapackages - their entire reason for existing is to pull in lots of other packages. they're for the convenience for those who don't want to have to individually select packages.

Comment: since you've already installed the meta-packages, you'll need to use `apt-mark` to flag the packages you want as being manually installed `apt-mark manual pkg1 pkg2 pkg2 ....`.  This will prevent them from being uninstalled when the meta-packaged is removed.

Comment: @cas I do not seem to get this to work. After running `sudo apt-mark manual kde-plasma-desktop` it just tells me `kde-plasma-desktop was already set to manually installed`. Nothing changed executing this command and `sudo apt-get remove konqueror` still has the same result.

Comment: you misunderstood me.  mark **the packages you want to keep installed** as manual, not the meta-packages.   i.e. the kde app packages listed in the Depends: line of kde-baseapps and/or task-kde-desktop etc that you want to keep.  then kde-baseapps can be removed without causing anything you want to be flagged for removal.    the meta-packages install everything.  you don't want some of that, so you'll have to remove the meta packages and manually install the ones you want (or mark them as manual if already installed).

Comment: or, far easier, just don't bother.  disk space is not at a premium these days, the programs don't do anything if you don't run them (or cause another program like a file-manager to execute them), they just waste a little disk space.  i.e. little or no harm, and probably not worth the bother of doing anything about.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the `kde-standard` package is not what you would like to install in the first place as a user who wants to have fine-grained control over the packages on your system.  Given the large list of things that you do not want, I would recommend removing `kde-standard` and installing `plasma-kde-desktop`.  The latter is like a minimal KDE.

However, we can also tell the package manager that we installed all of the `kde-standard` dependencies and recommendations manually and not as a dependency.  For this high-level task, it is always more comfortable to use `aptitude` as your interface to the package manager (`apt-get install aptitude` - https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude ).  Then the magic is done with:

```
aptitude  unmarkauto "?reverse-depends(kde-standard) | ?reverse-recommends(kde-standard)
```

Note: Before running such commands, I always recommend running aptitude in a first dry-run pass with the `-s` flag; that simulates the actions to be performed.

After this, you can remove the `kde-standard` package (`aptitude remove kde-standard`), and then proceed to removing the undesired packages.  Depending on the way you installed KDE, `aptitude` may also recommend removing the `task-kde-desktop`, which can be safely acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove kde-baseapps kdenlive* kdepim* kdeplasma* kde-* kde* && sudo apt purge kde-baseapps kdenlive* kdepim* kdeplasma* kde-* kde* && sudo apt autoremove -y
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the meta packages. 
   `sudo apt remove kde-standard kde-plasma-desktop` 
   **Confirm that the *only packages* under "REMOVED" is `kde-standard`, and `kde-plasma-desktop` so you don't uninstall your entire desktop**. You should see a ton of packages under "no longer required", that's okay. Keep a note of them for later.
2. Immediately mark `plasma-desktop` as manually installed. 
   `sudo apt install plasma-desktop`
3. Remember the packages under "no longer required"? Look through each of them and manually install each one you want to keep. Here is what I did: 
   `sudo apt install dolphin gwenview kate kcalc kde-spectacle ark plasma-nm sweeper`
4. Uninstall the orphaned packages. 
   `sudo apt autoremove`
   **Make a final note of all the queued packages.** For good measure, save the uninstall log to a file that you can refer to if you're missing a package.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt -y install kde-plasma-desktop plasma-nm
```

This will install a minimal installation about a gig smaller than the default KDE.

I "accidently" removed KDE and the above got me going again.

Answer (score -1):

I normally use

```
sudo apt purge **package-name**
```

to do this. I did it right now as a test, trying to remove okular and it marked only *kile*, *kile-l10n* and *okular* to remove (*kile* depends on *okular* to run). Did you tried it?

And if it try to remove everything, you can agree with it (on console, not inside Plasma) and then install *kde-baseapps*, to install only the minimal. From there you can install other packages that you want.

But I didn't realize why do you consider *okular* and *gwenview* as bloatware. Don't you open PDF or image files? Or do you use another softwares to do this?

Comment: Since he `kde-standard` is installed, this will lead to the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I used:

```
sudo apt install $(dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W)
```

to mark all packages as being manually installed.
after that I can pick any package to uninstall